# Scrape global website rank from SimilarWeb in Google sheets (using ImportXml)

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to scrape a global rank number from SimilarWeb website to display in a cell.
I had been using command made for Alexa rank website, however they unfortunately retired and it doesn't work anymore.
The command for Alexa rank was this:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url="WEBSITE LINK,"//POPULARITY/@TEXT")
```

Would anyone know how to write a command that could display the global rank, but from Similar web website?
For example https://www.similarweb.com/website/google.com/ is link for Google, where the global rank is no. 1. I need to scrape the no. 1 to my spreadsheet.
Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you, Kristyna

Comment: what is the complete and exact url you are looking for in importxml?

Comment: Hi Mike, do you mean the url I want to use to scrape the data from? It can be for example https://www.similarweb.com/website/google.com/
I'm not sure if that's what you asked..
I do not know the url of Similarweb "with the data" though....

Comment: If the content is added dynamically (by using Javascript), it can't be imported by using Google Sheets built-in functions.. See here : https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/how-to-know-if-google-sheets-importdata-importfeed-importhtml-or-importxml-fun , and I did'nt found any other way for this site. There is however a big json inside the code source but I was unable to fetch and parse it correctly.